# Should I align grout lines on the opposite walls?

Tags: tile, tiling

I'm preparing to tile above the bathtub, and because of the niche, the plan is to shift everything a bit up so the bottom side of the niche meets a separate tile. It would require making the top tile a bit shorter, but should look good. The problem is that on the vanity side (right wall) tile is already done, so it might be visible that the grout lines on the opposite walls are not aligned.

[image]

Am I overthinking this or is it actually looking bad?

Comment: Tough one.  The door and window will limit the difference some, but will probably still be visible.  Any chance of making the bottom tile shorter instead?  People would notice the top first/more than the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only way to alight the top/bottom sides of the niche with the tile. The alternative is to not alight them, but then I'll need to 1)  cut a rectangle inside a large-format tile + miter the edges, hard to do 2) have an additional grout line since tile edge and niche edge won't merge in one

Comment: Just my opinion, but I wouldn't worry about those lines not meeting.

Comment: Will there be a shower curtain or door?

Answer (score 2):

The professional way would be to make the grout lines match.

That said, if I understand it correctly, the lines will never touch each other.
It's just tile on one side of the room and tile on the other side.

If the real difference between the height of the lines is say, 2 inches or less it very well may not be noticeable to anyone except those with prior knowledge that the lines do not match.

In the end it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

I think only you can call it. It depends on your degree of OCD. It would drive me barking mad, every single time I saw it. Others may never even notice.

Presumably you're going to have to use cuts at one end or the other, why not at the bottom so it will all line up? It's going to look pretty odd if one side has cuts at the top but not the other - especially [which I didn't spot until I zoomed the picture] as the tiles are clearly patterned.

[image]